# how to implement infinite scrolling in nstableview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scroll, infinite

i am new in objective c, cocoa framework os x.

NSTableView is what I am using to display more data after reaching bottom of the NSTableview.

So what I decided to get response in pages say 1-100 then 101-200 etc. similar to Facebook and all other sites.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess we need more input - do you already **have** all the data and just want to lazy load? Do you want to load data **on demand** e.g. from a web service..?

Comment: yes i've already all the data and want to load 1-100 then 101-200. Actually, I'm confused in how to detect that we reached the last row of NSTableView in osx cocoa.

Comment: Ok - did you actually test this is an issue at all? AFAIR table view does already contain lazy loading logic and will only ask for the data (either via bindings or the delegate) when it actually needs to display them

Comment: Ok- is there any way to detect the scroll is reached at the last row of NSTableView?